# how can we compress a folder of our system using nodeJs with less memory

Tags: node.js

please help me with suitable solution creating .zip file for a folder with 
    less size.

```
var FolderZip= require("folder-zip");
 var options = {
excludeParentFolder: true, 
parentFolderName: 'v1.0' 
};

//zip a folder and change folder destination name
var zip = new FolderZip();
zip.zipFolder('./ExpressJs_sqlite3', options, function(){
zip.writeToFile('myfolder.zip');
});
/**it working properly but generated myfolder.zip size is more than the size 
of folder ExpressJs_sqlite3 
please help me with suitable solution creating .zip file for a folder with 
less size.
kindly requesting you please dont put negative votes. It blocks me asking 
more questions am a new learner need your help. **/
```

Answer (score 0):

yes... I got a solution.
using npm install easy-zip

```
//compress.js
var EasyZip = require('easy-zip').EasyZip;
var zip = new EasyZip();
 //zip a folder 
zip.zipFolder('D:/sourav/sample/CRUD ExpressJs_sqlite3',function(){
zip.writeToFile('D:/sourav/sample/CRUD ExpressJs_sqlite3.zip');
});
```